# Stack images with "hstack"-filter from video or image sequence in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, filter

Is it possible to input a video and extract images every second while simultaneously stack them horizontally or vertically with the **"hstack"** filter to create one jpg image?

The only way I can figure out how to do it is by extractning the still-frames with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mov -vf fps=1 -s 192x108 thumbnails%03d.jpg
```

And then inputting them one by one and then specifying then number of inputs like this.

```
ffmpeg -y -i thumbnails001.jpg -i thumbnails002.jpg -i thumbnails003.jpg... filter_complex vstack=inputs=3 output.jpg
```

It would be nice if it was possible to do in one more dynamic chunk from the original video or at least from one inputted Video-Sequence and not manually inserting the number of INPUTS needed to create the Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using the `tile` filter for this:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mov -vf fps=1,scale=192:108,tile=54x1 output.jpg
```

The tile argument is the size of a rectangle. So for a 54 second video, `54x1` produces a horizontal stack of 54 frames. Use `1x54` for a vertical stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. 
Is it possible to specify what frame number each second it should choose? Now for a 25fps clip it seems to choose frame 13. I would like it to choose the first frame each second.

Comment: Replace `fps=1` with `select='not(mod(n,25))'`

Comment: Once again, many thanks! 
I needed to add it whithin "" in this filter chain. Now it works.

`-vf "select='not(mod(n,25))'",scale=960:540,colormatrix=bt709:bt601,tile=30x1`